# remove gaps in timeseries ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, geom-bar

I'd like to remove the gaps between my data points when plotting a timeseries in ggplot: [image]

Ideally I'd like the plot to look like the below, however with my x-axis as a `POSIX.ct` object so that I can dictate the line breaks etc.

[image: Plot with date as a factor]

I'm doing hundreds of these plots in a loop, therefore I can't afford to have  my date as a factor like in the second plot.

Is there a way to remove the gaps in the timeseries, without having to have date as a factor, but as a `date` or `POSIXct` instead?

`dput` with subset of my data is below.

Thanks in advance

```
structure(list(Sample.Date = structure(c(1604667600, 1604840400, 
1605013200, 1605186000, 1605531600, 1604062800, 1604149200, 1604235600, 
1604322000, 1604408400, 1604494800, 1604581200, 1604667600, 1604754000, 
1604840400, 1605013200, 1605186000, 1605531600, 1606654800, 1610888400, 
1611666000, 1615208400, 1618840800, 1619964000, 1621173600, 1622383200, 
1625407200, 1626616800, 1627826400, 1629036000, 1631109600, 1606395600, 
1607259600, 1610283600, 1612789200, 1632060000, 1613998800, 1606654800, 
1610888400, 1611666000, 1615208400, 1618840800, 1619964000, 1621173600, 
1622383200, 1625407200, 1626616800, 1627826400, 1629036000, 1631109600, 
1606395600, 1607259600, 1610283600, 1612789200, 1632060000, 1613998800
), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Site = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("", "MHFR01", "MHFR08", 
"MHFR10", "MHFR11", "MHFR12"), class = "factor"), Site.72hr.weather = structure(c(10L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
12L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
11L), .Label = c("", "MHFR01-INT", "MHFR01 DRY", "MHFR01 WET", 
"MHFR08-INT", "MHFR08 DRY", "MHFR08 WET", "MHFR10-INT", "MHFR10 DRY", 
"MHFR10 WET", "MHFR11-INT", "MHFR11 DRY", "MHFR11 INT", "MHFR11 WET", 
"MHFR12-INT", "MHFR12 DRY", "MHFR12 INT", "MHFR12 WET"), class = "factor"), 
    Rainfall.72hr = c(29, 0, 0, 6, 0, 23, 11, 17, 15, 6, 5, 29, 
    29, 24, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, 7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, 7, 4, 2, 5, 1), Weather = structure(c(4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("", "DRY", "INT", 
    "WET"), class = "factor"), Analyte = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Ammonia.NH3.N.mg.L", 
    "Enterococci.CFU.100mL", "Enterococci.log10", "Faecal.Coliform.CFU.100mL", 
    "Faecal.Coliform.log10", "Field.dissolved.oxygen.mg.L", "Nitrate.mg.L", 
    "Nitrite.mg.L", "Oxidised.Nitrogen.mg.L", "Percent.Dissolved.Oxygen...sat", 
    "Total.Nitrogen.mg.L", "Total.Phosphorus.mg.L"), class = "factor"), 
    Concentration = c(2.113943352, 0.954242509, 0.954242509, 
    1.255272505, 1.602059991, 4.51851394, 4.681241237, 3.799340549, 
    3.146128036, 3.380211242, 4.477121255, 3.924279286, 2.77815125, 
    2.505149978, 4.602059991, 4.544068044, 3.944482672, 4.230448921, 
    0.954242509, 2.72427587, 2.568201724, 0.653212514, 0.653212514, 
    1.602059991, 0.954242509, 2.230448921, 1.301029996, 1, 1.838849091, 
    0.653212514, 1, 2, 1.653212514, 2.278753601, 2.278753601, 
    1.301029996, 1.69019608, 2.672097858, 2.342422681, 2.72427587, 
    3.301029996, 2.176091259, 2.414973348, 2.939519253, 2.579783597, 
    1.954242509, 2.204119983, 1.770852012, 1.913813852, 2.397940009, 
    2.799340549, 2.698970004, 2.612783857, 2.477121255, 2.342422681, 
    2.755874856), Period = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Pre", "During", "Post"), class = "factor"), 
    Date_fct = structure(c(8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 
    22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 14L, 16L, 
    17L, 20L, 32L, 21L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 32L, 21L), .Label = c("2020-10-31", 
    "2020-11-01", "2020-11-02", "2020-11-03", "2020-11-04", "2020-11-05", 
    "2020-11-06", "2020-11-07", "2020-11-08", "2020-11-09", "2020-11-11", 
    "2020-11-13", "2020-11-17", "2020-11-27", "2020-11-30", "2020-12-07", 
    "2021-01-11", "2021-01-18", "2021-01-27", "2021-02-09", "2021-02-23", 
    "2021-03-09", "2021-04-20", "2021-05-03", "2021-05-17", "2021-05-31", 
    "2021-07-05", "2021-07-19", "2021-08-02", "2021-08-16", "2021-09-09", 
    "2021-09-20"), class = "factor"), Mon_Yr = structure(c(2020.83333333333, 
    2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 
    2020.75, 2020.75, 2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 
    2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 
    2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 2020.83333333333, 
    2020.83333333333, 2021, 2021, 2021.16666666667, 2021.25, 
    2021.33333333333, 2021.33333333333, 2021.33333333333, 2021.5, 
    2021.5, 2021.58333333333, 2021.58333333333, 2021.66666666667, 
    2020.83333333333, 2020.91666666667, 2021, 2021.08333333333, 
    2021.66666666667, 2021.08333333333, 2020.83333333333, 2021, 
    2021, 2021.16666666667, 2021.25, 2021.33333333333, 2021.33333333333, 
    2021.33333333333, 2021.5, 2021.5, 2021.58333333333, 2021.58333333333, 
    2021.66666666667, 2020.83333333333, 2020.91666666667, 2021, 
    2021.08333333333, 2021.66666666667, 2021.08333333333), class = "yearmon")), row.names = c(NA, 
-56L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue with factors and plotting in a loop. But no, as far as I know there is no way to display a `POSIXct `/`date` object discontinuously, nor an easy hack to handle the formatting of a factor as if it were such class.

Comment: Variable **Concentrations** has more than one measurement per day - do you want to aggregate values per day or show one line per measurement?